# Google Docs Embedded document giving errors

Tags: google-docs

When loading an embedded google document on my site. I get the following error on my website:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DOCS_timing is not defined
    at pub?
```

Link has been generated on google docs at https://docs.google.com/ .

My link is in the following format: (with ... meaning a large amount of seemingly random characters)

```
"https://docs.google.com/document/d/ ... /export?format=pdf";
```

This is my iframe that I have been using and I would expect it to work. This in in JSX.

```
<iframe
        name={"Cv"}
        src={source}
        onLoad={loadingDone}
        style={styleiFrame}
        allow="picture-in-picture full">
</iframe>
```

Cv shows up nicely, but it gives those errors every now and then.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, the Google Docs is showing fine in the website however I get the same error in the console. It would also be beneficial if you could submit this to the [Google Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) to further investigate it.